# extract number from string in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I am trying to extract a specific text from an Outlook subject line. This is required to calculate turn around time for each order entered in SAP. I have a subject line as below

```
SO# 3032641559 FW: Attached new PO 4500958640- 13563 TYCO  LJ
```

My final output should be like this: 3032641559

I have been able to do this in MS excel with the formulas like this

```
=IFERROR(INT(MID([@[Normalized_Subject]],SEARCH(30,[@[Normalized_Subject]]),10)),"Not Found")
```

in the above formula `[@[Normalized_Subject]]` is the name of column in which the SO number exists. I have asked to do this in oracle but I am very new to this. Your help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Note: in the above subject line the number 30 is common in every subject line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755681/use-regexp-instr-to-get-the-last-number-in-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last parameter of [`REGEXP_SUBSTR()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions150.htm#sthref1429) indicates the sub-expression you want to pick. In this case you can't just match 30 then some more numbers as the second set of digits might have a 30. So, it's safer to match the following, where x are more digits.

```
SO# 30xxxxxx
```

As a regular expression this becomes:

```
SO#\s30\d+
```

where `\s` indicates a space `\d` indicates a numeric character and the `+` that you want to match as many as there are. But, we can use the sub-expression substringing available; in order to do that you need to have sub-expressions; i.e. create groups where you want to split the string:

```
(SO#\s)(30\d+)
```

Put this in the function call and you have it:

```
regexp_substr(str, '(SO#\s)(30\d+)', 1, 1, 'i', 2)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/16991)

Comment: @santhosha . . . This looks like the correct answer.  You should accept it if you agree.